# How I can add custom config in categories in magento2

Tags: magento2, category

I need Add custom config to magento 2 category.
I Add in my module view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

<fieldset name="search_engine_optimization_templates" sortOrder="80">
    <settings>
        <collapsible>true</collapsible>
        <label translate="true">Search Engine Optimization TEMPLATES</label>
    </settings>

    <field name="meta_title_template" sortOrder="160" formElement="input">
        <settings>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Meta Title Template</label>
        </settings>
    </field>

    <field name="meta_keywords_template" sortOrder="170" formElement="input">
        <settings>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Meta Keywords Template</label>
        </settings>
    </field>

    <field name="meta_description_template" sortOrder="180" formElement="input">
        <settings>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Meta Description Template</label>
        </settings>
    </field>

    <field name="template_weight" sortOrder="190" formElement="input">
        <settings>
            <dataType>string</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Template Weight</label>
        </settings>
    </field>
</fieldset>
```

Ok, i see in admin this:
[image]
But how i can save my custom parameters in database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a category attribute in order to save the value in database.

Try this

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    )
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'template_weight',
            [
                'type'         => 'varchar',
                'label'        => 'Template Weight',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'sort_order'   => 100,
                'source'       => '',
                'global'       => 1,
                'visible'      => true,
                'required'     => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default'      => null,
                'group'        => '',
                'backend'      => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you. It will help others too.